# Does the target .SUFFIX have any meaning in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, suffix

In a Makefile I encountered:

```
.SUFFIX: .c
```

Is that a misspelling of `.SUFFIXES: .c`, because I can't find anything about `.SUFFIX` only. Does this do anything at all?

If the Makefile only uses pattern rules, do I even need that hanging around in the Makefile at all?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using GNU make, unless there is really a user target named `.SUFFIX`, this is probably a misspelling of `.SUFFIXES: .c`. And if there is no recipe you can safely remove it: without a recipe it's useless.

If it was `.SUFFIXES: .c` and if it had a recipe it would redefine the implicit rules for:

```
%: %.c
    <recipe>
```

which is:

```
LINK.c = $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)

%: %.c
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```